# Bootstrap nav toggle without navbar element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

Is it possible to create the toggle button without using all the markup for default navigation?

I just want to create simple menu with the collapse feature. For example:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul id="nav-to-collapse">
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-to-collapse">
</div>
```

Would this be possible? Its my first time using Bootstrap (3) and Its really confusing. I dont want to use all the navbar classes because then I would have to overwrite all the navbar styles just to create simple menu that I want.

**EDIT:** I managed to create the toggle without all the useless navbar classes but there is an issue with the toggle animation, when nav height is changed. Here is a jsfiddle to ilustrate the problem: [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cfcZY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the collapse animation issue by using min-height instead of height on the nav element. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfcZY/2/

```
nav { min-height: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's toggle function is a javascript function that is triggered when the user clicks the element with an attribute of data-toggle="collapse". If there is not also a data-target="" id specified, then the element that the user clicks is collapsed. However, in this bit of markup:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-to-collapse">
```

The data-target="" attribute is set to the id of #nav-to-collapse. So Bootstrap's collapse plugin is going to look for an id="nav-to-collapse" and trigger its function on that id.

So in this markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

The data-target is set to the class of .navbar-collapse, which will make everything underneath that element collapse.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working without all the useless navbar classes. But there is one problem, when I set the nav height in css to anything else than auto, the collapse animation which pushed down the body content doesnt work. I created a fiddle so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/cfcZY/ . When you uncomment the nav { height: } declaration, it breaks.

Comment: That's because you are giving it a static height.  By setting the height of that container to 100px, it will expand out to 100px, but no more.  By setting it to auto, the container's height will expand to make room for all of the content inside that container.  If you need it to expand only to a certain height, you will have to both set the height of the container, then ensure that all of your content will fit into that container (by changing to font-size of the nav links, for example).

Comment: Yeah, I though it creates new div below the nav and puts the links there. I fixed it by using min-height though :)